# Choosing two bases so that the matrix is in a certain form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the linear map given by $f(u)=Au$ for all $u \in \mathbb{R}^4$, where

$$A =\begin{pmatrix} 1&-3&4&5\\ -3&9&-12&-15\\ 4 & -12& 16& 20 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Find a basis $B$ for $\mathbb{R}^4$ and a basis $C$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the matrix of $f$ with respect to $B$ and $C$ is of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} I_r & 0_{r,4-r}\\ 0_{3-r,r} & 0_{3-r,4-r}\end{pmatrix}$$

where $r=\mathop{rank}(f)$. Here $I_r$ is the identity  $r\times r$-matrix and $0_{k,l}$ denotes the zero $k\times l$-matrix.

My attempt:

I have found that the rank of the matrix is 1 and to my understanding, to find a two bases with respect to the matrix, I would have to find a basis B that can be written as a linear combination of basis C to give the desired columns. How would I go about working that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B = (v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $C = (w_1,w_2,w_3)$ a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Check that you understand why $[f]_{B}^{C}$ (the matrix representing $f$ with respect to the bases $B$ and $C$) has the required form if and only if

$$ f(v_1) = w_1, f(v_2) = 0, f(v_3) = 0, f(v_4) = 0. $$

Use this to find (one of infinitely many possible) bases $B$ and $C$ for which $[f]_{B}^{C}$ has the required form.

Comment: Hi levap, I understand up until this point, however how would I use this information to find the basis? Would I arbitarily pick any $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4?$

Comment: I understand where this information is coming from however, I do not understand where to go from here, that is my problem? Thank you

Comment: Well, $v_2, v_3, v_4$ should belong to the kernel of $f$ and be a part of a basis. Since $\mathrm{dim} \ker f = 3$, they must form a basis for $\ker f$. The vector $v_1$ shouldn't be in the kernel of $f$ (because then it wouldn't be linearly independent of $v_2,v_3,v_4$). After finding $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$, you have $w_1 = f(v_1)$ and you can take $w_2,w_3$ to be any arbitrary two vectors that complete $w_1$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ because they play no role whatsoever in the equation above.

Comment: How would you find $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4?$

Comment: $v_2,v_3,v_4$ must form a basis for $\ker(f)$ (which you should know how to find, for example using Gaussian elimination) and $v_1$ should not belong to $\ker(f)$.

Comment: I'm really sorry I am really confused, would I find the basis of a kernel by reducing matrix A into echelon form and then plugging in values?

Comment: Yes, that is one way.

Comment: And so once I get a basis of the kernel, how would I ensure that $v_1$ is not in the kernel? Would I just ensure that it is linearly independent from $v_2,v_3,v_4?$

Comment: That will work. You can also take any $v_1$ with $f(v_1) \neq 0$ and it will be automatically linearly independent from $v_2,v_3,v_4$.

Comment: I see! So essentially I can pick $v_1$ to be anything I like as long as it isn't linearly dependent on $ker(f)$ and then pick a $w_1$ that satisfies the condition $f(v_1)=w_1$ and then arbitarily pick $w_2,w_3?$

Comment: Once you pick $v_1$, you don't have a choice about $w_1$ - it must be $w_1 = f(v_1)$. Afterwards, you don't completely arbitrary pick $w_2,w_3$ - you still need to make sure $(w_1,w_2,w_3)$ are linearly independent.